# jquery dynamically change data attribute value and calculate arithmetic operation(addition)

Tags: jquery

This is my script

```
 $(document).on('click', '.cnt', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var wa = $('#te').data('vals');
        va = wa + 1;
        console.log(va);
        $('#te').data('vals', va);
        $('#te').attr('data-vals', va);
    })
```

And here is my

```
<a href="" class="cnt">click me</a>
<div id="te" data-vals=1>count</div>
```

The above script not working properly as expected. Please find the [fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/3K5bw/1/)

Answer (score 1):

You can use **[.attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)** instead of `.data()` as well as using unary plus `+` before your value to parse `wa` value as integer in order to increase it as number:

```
$(document).on('click', '.cnt', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var wa = $('#te').attr('data-vals');
    va = +wa + 1;
    console.log(va);
    //$('#te').data('vals', va);    // This is not updating even once
    $('#te').attr('data-vals', va); // This is updating only once
});
```

**[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3K5bw/4/)**